# Can this program be improved so that when my enumerated choices are output to a text file all 4 of them are shown

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files, enumerate

```
choices = ['pizza', 'pasta', 'salad', 'nachos']

for index, item in enumerate(choices, start = 1):

          print (index, item)


          file = open("list.txt", "w")

          file.write(str(index))

          file.write(item)

          file.close()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `write` should be _in_ the loop, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it correct, the following should work:

```
choices = ['pizza', 'pasta', 'salad', 'nachos']

with open("list.txt", "w") as file:
    for index, item in enumerate(choices, start=1):
        print (index, item)
        file.write('{} {}\n'.format(index, item))
```

Which would give you output as follows:

```
1 pizza
2 pasta
3 salad
4 nachos
```

Using `with` has the effect of automatically closing your file for you afterwards.